# Sort a user input list of numbers using python bubble sort

Tags: python-3.x, bubble-sort

I've just started to learn python and I've decided to try and do a bubble sort. I've used the code below which works ok if the numbers to be sorted are 0 to 9. After that, it doesn't sort them correctly. I think, in my limited knowledge that this is because it is a 'list'.

I would like the user to be able to input the numbers but for the program to sort them regardless of the length of the number. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def bubble_sort(items):
    changes=0

    for i in range(len(items)):
        for j in range(len(items)-1-i):#-i = optimised??
            if items[j] > items[j+1]:
                items[j], items[j+1] = items[j+1], items[j]  # Swap
                changes=changes+1

    print(items)
    print("Number of passes =",i)
    print("Number of swaps =",changes)

print("Welcome to a Bubble Sort Algorithm in Python!")

while True:

    print("Enter as many numbers as you want.\n You can choose between 0 and 9.\nLeave a space between each one")
    numbers=input()
    items=numbers.split()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
print('welcome to the automatic bubble sorter')
inputted_list = input('please enter a list of numbers seperated by commas: ')
list = inputted_list.split(',')
number_of_items = int(len(list))

sorting_method = input('if you would like your list to be sorted in ascending order, press 1, if you would like it to be sorted in descending order, press 2')
print(list)

if sorting_method == '1':
    position = 0
    Pass = 0
    counter = 1
    while counter == 1:
        number_of_swaps = 1
        counter2 = 0
        permanent_numbers = []
        while number_of_swaps > 0:
            counter2 = counter2 + 1
            number_of_swaps = 0
            while position < number_of_items - 1:
                if int(list[position]) > int(list[position + 1]):
                    number_of_swaps = number_of_swaps + 1
                    item1 = int(list[position])
                    item2 = int(list[position + 1])
                    list[position] = item2
                    list[position + 1] = item1
                position = position + 1
            Pass =  Pass + 1
            print('pass',Pass,':',list)
            position = 0
            if Pass == number_of_items - 1:
                number_of_swaps = 0
            permanent_numbers.append(list[number_of_items - counter2])
        if number_of_swaps == 0:
            counter = 0


    print('total number of passes:', Pass)

    elif sorting_method == '2':
    position = 0
    Pass = 0
    counter = 1
    while counter == 1:
        number_of_swaps = 1
        while number_of_swaps > 0:
            number_of_swaps = 0
            while position < number_of_items - 1:
                if int(list[position]) > int(list[position + 1]):
                    number_of_swaps = number_of_swaps + 1
                    item1 = int(list[position])
                    item2 = int(list[position + 1])
                    list[position] = item2
                    list[position + 1] = item1
                position = position + 1
            Pass =  Pass + 1
            print('pass',Pass,':',list)
            position = 0
            if Pass == number_of_items - 1:
                number_of_swaps = 0

        if number_of_swaps == 0:
            counter = 0


    print('total number of passes:', Pass)
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>try [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):</s>

I suggested using map before, but I just remembered that map in python 3.x* yields a generator rather than a list, so that is why you cannot take the length of it. The updated answer is below

```
numbers = input("Enter as many numbers as you want.\n You can choose between 0 and 9.\nLeave a space between each one")
items = [int(num) for num in numbers.split()]
```

Modified existing code:

```
#!/usr/bin
def bubble_sort(items):
    changes = passes = 0
    last = len(items)
    swapped = True

    while swapped:
        swapped = False
        passes += 1
        for j in range(1, last):
            if items[j - 1] > items[j]:
                items[j], items[j - 1] = items[j - 1], items[j]  # Swap
                changes += 1
                swapped = True
                last = j


    print(items)
    print("Number of passes =",passes)
    print("Number of swaps =",changes)


print("Welcome to a Bubble Sort Algorithm in Python!")

while True:
    print("Enter as many numbers as you want.\n You can choose between 0 and 9.\nLeave a space between each one")
    numbers = input()
    items = [int(num) for num in numbers.split() if num.isdigit()]
    if items: bubble_sort(items)
```

Comment: An example of usage might be helpful

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand why that will work. My only problem is that now I am getting "TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()"                           Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: @stacksth can you show how you are using map in your code?

Comment: @stacksth, I think I know what the problem is, see my updated post

Answer (score 0):

```
def b_sort(list):

for iter_num in range(len(list)-1,0,-1):
    for idx in range(iter_num):

        if list[idx] > list[idx+1]:
            temp = list[idx]
            list[idx] = list[idx+1]
            list[idx+1] = temp

str_input= input("Enter numbers:  ")
list = [int(x) for x in str_input.split()]

b_sort(list)
print('sorted elements are: ')
print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sort():
    try:
        n = [1,8,6]
        l = len(n)
        print("Original list:", n)
        for i in range(l - 1):
            for j in range(0,l - i - 1):
                if n[j] > n[j + 1]:
                    n[j], n[j + 1] = n[j + 1], n[j]
        print("List after sorting is:", n)
    except:
        print("Error in inputing values")


sort()
```

Comment: Please, do not add simply code, but try to explain why this is the correct way to solve the OP problem